# C# Stop Person From Typing In Option In Drop Down Combo Box

Tags: c#, input, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down combo box with items in, just wondered whether there was an option to stop people from typing in it, and only allow them to select an item that is already in there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 7):

WinForms:

---

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

WPF:

---

```
comboBox.IsReadOnly = true;
comboBox.IsEditable = false;
```

Comment: Are you sure the WPF version should have `IsEditable = true;`? ReadOnly and Editable both true just doesn't seem likely to me. :)

Comment: Now both false? ;) Try IsReadonly = true and IsEditable = false, maybe?

Comment: @Ken White: This is what happens when I visit SO while I'm at work.  I need to slow down =D

Answer (score 4):

The others have covered a WinForms combo box; for completeness, in WPF you have to set `IsReadOnly = true` and `IsEditable = false`.